# LINQ query update to accommodate changes

Tags: vb.net

I need help in combining below SQL to code

```vb
Dim queryPersons = Query.From("ADSAccountInADSGroup") _
                  .Where(Function(t) t.Column("UID_ADSAccount") = uidAdsAccount) _
                  .SelectAll()
```

I'm successfull only until `UID_ADsAccount = '4f58406f-8823-4530-b763-d344fc9093ed')`

I need to append below piece of code as well to `Dim queryPersons`

```vb
and uid_adsgroup not in(select uid_adsgroup from adsgroup where cn  like 'Domain%'))
and (XMarkedForDeletion <> 2) and (XOrigin = 1)))
```

Comment: We need more information. Do you have an object structure/model with types and at least one example of sample data? Name of the list you're working on?

Comment: Are you asking how to add in the extra conditions in your 2nd code block to the Where clause of the first code block?  Have you read up on AndAlso?